# Amazon EC2 Ubuntu problems with apt-get?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.10

I am running ubuntu 10.10 64bit using the stock ami on a micro ec2, when i try to install apache i get

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

is the apt package not installed on the EC2 AMIs?

if so how do i get apt back or work around it?

Comment: whats the output from uname -a?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a path issue try

`sudo /usr/bin/apt-get ...`

You can set the path that sudo will search with the `secure_path` directive in the sudoers file

> secure_path
>
> Path used for every command run from
>   sudo.  If you don’t trust the people
>   running sudo to have a sane PATH
>   environment variable you may want to
>   use this.  Another use is if you want
>   to have the "root path" be separate
>   from the "user path."  Users in the
>   group specified by the exempt_group
>   option are not affected by
>   secure_path.  This is not set by
>   default.

Answer (score 1):

Do dpkg -l |grep apt and have a look if the package is really installed. If yes, try to use /usr/bin/apt-get instead of apt-get.

If apt-get is not installed and it is indeed an Ubuntu system, something is wrong with your installation. One week ago, I installed the same OS on a test EC2 instance, and apt-get worked from the very beginning.

Maybe you "reinstall" your instance by deleting and recreating it? Are you sure that it is really an Ubuntu?

Try

```
cat /etc/issue
```

and have a look - maybe you missclicked and used the wrong image.